# Matlab Umtoggle obsolete

Tags: matlab, interface

I have some problems with Matlab plotgui. I have Matlab 7.6.0 (R2008a) in Windows XP. When I use the graphical interface for PLS-DA, I want to explore the numbers and table of my plot from the plot controls, but I have the following message:

PLOTGUI ERROR USING UMTOGGLE AT 9. UMTOGGLE FUNCTION IS OBSOLETE. SET THE CHECKED PROPERTY OF UIMENU INSTEAD. 
Please can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Carolina D.A.

Comment: What didn't work about this? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/105697-umtoggle-invalid-function-in-plotguide

Comment: I've tried with Matlab answers but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: plEASE ANY OTHER COMMENTS FOR MY PROBLEM?

Comment: DBSTOP IF ERROR and dbup how do I use thme? I've tried but nothing appears thanks!!!